# Add SubView over TabBar and their Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller, addsubview

i`m trying to add a View over the all TabBarController, I tried this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,
        CGRectGetWidth(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds),
        CGRectGetHeight(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)))
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let tabBar : UITabBarController = UITabBarControllerHelper.generate() //Create the TabBarController, works fine
    let videoController : UIViewController = VideoViewController()
    videoController.view.layer.zPosition = 1
    tabBar.view.addSubview(videoController.view)
    self.window!.rootViewController = tabBar
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

But this don`t work, only TabBarController is rendered. I changed the `self.window!.rootViewController` to test to draw the videoController and works fine too. The problem is: I can`t merge the views.